# Razor Html.DropDownListFor automatically set the selected value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am new to Razor, I pass dropdown list as a viewbag and another values, when drop down list show in web it has selected values but i haven't set the any selected value, I think I use same name in viewbag value and dropdownlist value,it can be happen?

This is the viewbag,here i set the values and drop downlist:

```
ViewBag.GlobalInstance = globalInstance;
ViewBag.LegislativeCode = legislativeCode.Trim();
ViewBag.Legislatives = new SelectList(legislativeEntities, "LegislativeCode", "LegislativeName");
```

This is frontend code:

```
@if (ViewBag.GlobalInstance == true)
{
        <div class="col-xs-5 hcm-form_controller mandatory gap" >
            <label for="LegislativeCode" class="w-100" mi-resourcekey="atr-LegislativeCode" >Legislative Entity</label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LegislativeCode, ViewBag.Legislatives as SelectList, "--- Select ---", new { @class = "calc-w-100" })
        </div>
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual html code of the `select` control that is rendered on the page? Also note, that by default the first `option` item from your select list will be shown as selected (if no other option item has the `selected` attribute set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the page model has a value for LegislativeCode,

```
m => m.LegislativeCode
```

so when there is a same `LegislativeCode` in the `ViewBag.Legislatives`, this option will be selected.